Does ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf accept shell environment variables?
I need to add my GPG key to some lines in
~/.gnupg/gpg.conf
such as
default-key XXX
default-recipient XXX

Does it accept shell environment variables? Can I use
default-key $GPGKEY
default-recipient $GPGKEY

where $GPGKEY is defined in my shell initialization file so I don't have to remember updating it when my keys are regenerated in future?
